# "React is not defined"

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, viro-react

I'm very new to react-native & Viro-react platforms. Currently, I'm working on an AR/VR app for my final year project. In that project, I need to apply redux functionality and implement a common store for my entire application. I've created `store/index.js` (store), `store/reducer/index.js` (root reducer) & `store/reducer/initial_Reducer.js`, `store/actions/initial_Action.js` correctly. following are them.

store/index.js (store)

```
import rootReducer from './reducers';
import {createStore} from 'redux';

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default store;
```

store/reducer/index.js (root reducer)

```
import initial_Reducer from './initial_Reducer';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    initial_Reducer: initial_Reducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

store/reducer/initial_Reducer.js

```
const initial_Reducer = (state = {store:true}, action) => {
    console.log("Initial Reducer..");
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'initialize': {
            return state;
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default initial_Reducer;
```

store/actions/initial_Action.js

```
export const initializeStore = () => {
    console.log("Initial Action..");
    return {
        type: 'initialize'
    }
}
```

When I try to apply the store to  with  tag, it gives me the following error.

```
React is not defined
```

[Please check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEUXB.jpg)

My index.js & index.android.js are as follows.

index.js

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App.js';

import store from './store/index'; //importing redux store config from store/index.js
import { Provider } from 'react-redux/src'; //importing binding layer from reac-redux

// The below line is necessary for use with the TestBed App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('ViroSample', () =>
    <Provider store={store} >
        <App />
    </Provider>
);
```

index.android.js

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App.js';

import store from './store/index'; //importing redux store config from store/index.js
import { Provider } from 'react-redux/src' //importing binding layer from reac-redux

// The below line is necessary for use with the TestBed App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('ViroSample', () =>
    <Provider store={store} >
        <App />
    </Provider>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should import React in both files `index.android.js` and `index.js`

```
import React from "react";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `import 'react';` in all files containing JSX and don’t utilize React explicit.

In your case this are `index.android.js` and `index.js` and rename these files form *.js to *.jsx.